# configure: error: Cannot enable MemorySanitizer ubuntu18.04

Tags: 18.04, gcc, c++, c

make powerdns in ubuntu18.04 server by this option  ./configure  --enable-msan and I install 100+ packages but it could resolve

error

checking whether to enable MemorySanitizer... yes

checking whether C++ compiler handles -fsanitize=memory... no

configure: error: Cannot enable MemorySanitizer

Comment: Is it 14.04 or 18.04?

Comment: ubuntu-18.04.5-live-server-amd64

Comment: OK so why the 14.04 flag? Do I understand this correctly you have not installed this and you are running only from the live CD?

Comment: Are your following some instructions? if so, please link them. I suspect that `-fsanitize=memory` requires clang++ in place of g++

Comment: https://dnsdist.org/install.html   ./configure --help I want to enable Optional Features which are given but --enable-msan  is not working